# Problemas al cerrar desplegable haciendo click en el botón

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Tengo un problema con un botón desplegable.

Lo que quiero de este botón es que cuando haga clic fuera del botón se cerrará "que ya hace", pero cuando hago clic en el botón para cerrar, se abrirá de nuevo. ¿Por qué no cerrar?

No sé cómo hacerlo, he venido aquí y no salgo de este callejón.

```js
var toggle = $('[data-toggle]');

        toggle.click(function(event) {

            $("ul.dropdown-menu").hide();

            var el = $(this).attr('data-toggle');
            $("#" + el).slideToggle();

            // Cerramos el desplegable cuando se hace click en cualquier lugar del DOM
            if($("#" + el).parent(".btn-group").length > 0 ){
                $(window).click(function() {
                    $("#" + el).slideUp(function(){
                        $(window).unbind("click");
                    });          
                });
            }
            event.stopPropagation();
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group"> 
        <button data-toggle="opcion-servicios-contrant" class="btn dropdown-toggle">Contratar <span class="caret"></span> </button>
        <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu" id="opcion-servicios-contrant"> 
          <li><a href="#">Cambio de WIFI</a></li> 
          <li><a href="#">Autodiagnóstico de niveles MTA</a></li> 
          <li><a href="#">Recuperación de contraseña del WIFI</a></li> 
          <li><a href="#">Velocimetro</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contratar upgrade</a></li>
         </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Hola buenas! Esto es StackOverflow en Español asi que las pregunta han de estar en español. Si quieres hacer tu pregunta en inglés, publicala en http://stackoverflow.com. Para traducirla, puedes [editar](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/43867/edit) tu pregunta

Comment: Lo siento!!! no me había dado cuenta que me pasó a stackoverflow en español..

Comment: No pasa nada. hahah hay muchos despistes.

Comment: La traducción en español no la entiendo. No sé cual es el problema ni lo que quieres conseguir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supongo, que lo que querías hacer es de no mostrar el menu a la primera para eso tienes que sacar el `hide` del `toggle`.

```js
var toggle = $('[data-toggle]');

$("ul.dropdown-menu").hide(); // Aquí

toggle.click(function(event) {
  
  var el = $(this).attr('data-toggle');
  $("#" + el).slideToggle();

  // Cerramos el desplegable cuando se hace click en cualquier lugar del DOM
  if($("#" + el).parent(".btn-group").length > 0 ){
    $(window).click(function() {
      $("#" + el).slideUp(function(){
        $(window).unbind("click");
      });          
    });
  }
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group"> 
  <button data-toggle="opcion-servicios-contrant" class="btn dropdown-toggle">Contratar <span class="caret"></span> </button>
  <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu" id="opcion-servicios-contrant"> 
    <li><a href="#">Cambio de WIFI</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">Autodiagnóstico de niveles MTA</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">Recuperación de contraseña del WIFI</a></li> 
    <li><a href="#">Velocimetro</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contratar upgrade</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias!! Eso era :'(

Comment: tengo un problema... ahora este mismo codigo tiene 2 botones y al hacer click en los 2 botones se me abren los 2. Necesito que al abrir uno se me cierre el otro pero no lo doi conseguido :(

Comment: comprueba que no llames al mismo id del data-toggle en el otro botón